# How to use a Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, virtualenv

I am using Python 3.7.9 Shell.

I created a virtual environment in this location
C:\Users\my_username\Desktop\Projects.venv

Inside of Python Shell, when I type: import numpy, which is in my .venv\lib folder, it says that the module does not exist.

Using Python Shell, how do I make use of the contents in .venv? In particular, the libraries located there?

**Edit #1: Include Details**

- In my windows command line, it has (.venv) off to the left.
- I have run the Activate file. I then started Python.
- In my \lib\site-packages area, I have the requests library.
- When I open up Python Shell and type "import requests", it says "no such library can be found"
- I am using Windows 10
- I installed the libraries while in the (.venv) environment.

**Theory:**
In the virtual environment, in Python Shell, it's searching a different location for libraries...now if I can just figure out where it's searching and how to change that...I might be able to make progress.

**Edit #2: My Progress**

My theory was correct. Despite using a virtual environment, it's not looking for the libraries installed in `(.venv)\lib\site-packages,` it's looking somewhere outside of that.

Now I just need to figure out how to make the Python code look for libraries inside of (.venv)\lib\site-packages when I'm in the virtual environment.

When I run the python.exe file inside of the (.venv)\Scripts location, it recognizes the virtual environment scripts.

If I click on my version of Python.Exe located in my C:...\Programs\Python 3.7 folder, it doesn't recognize them.

I was under the impression it didn't matter where I clicked on the Python.exe file if I did it after going to the virtual environment in the command line? Is this not true?

**Edit #3: Important Links**

- [Where Python Looks for Modules When Importing](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/sys_path.html)

Comment: in your shell, activate the venv by sourcing `bin/activate`

Comment: explain further please?

Comment: @ti7: "sourcing"? You mean "run" or something like that?

Comment: **after** activating your venv in your current shell, are you installing requests via `python -m pip install requests` or some other way?

Comment: No, I am not. Need more characters to submit my comment, here they are.

Comment: Did more investigating, please see bottom of Edit #2.

Answer (score 1):

Right from the official docs   https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments

> Once you’ve created a virtual environment, you may activate it.
>
> On Windows, run:
>
> ```
> tutorial-env\Scripts\activate.bat
> ```
>
> On Unix or MacOS, run:
>
> ```
> source tutorial-env/bin/activate
> ```

this is done in your shell before starting `python` at its prompt, and allows you to choose different python versions in addition to other benefits

Comment: in my windows command line, it has (.venv) off to the left. I have run the Activate file. I then started Python. 

In my \lib\site-packages area, I have the requests library.

When I open up Python Shell and type "import requests", it says "no such library can be found".

Comment: this begs a lot of questions! how did you install it? are you using some IDE which is "helping" you?

Comment: I'll answer all questions in my original post because if you have them, others might have them too.

I am only using Python Shell. I was in the .venv environment when I installed the libraries.

Comment: It doesn't "beg a lot of questions" — fairly straight-forward IMO.

Comment: I kinda figured it out. Opening python shell after using command line to go into the (.venv) environment, it is using libraries installed somewhere else.

Comment: Found the problem, please see the bottom of my 2nd update.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - indeed, it needs to be launched from a shell which has has the venv activated! .. this is largely due to it manipulating PATH-like vars (I don't have a complete list, but at least `PYTHONPATH`) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)